# Store references to elements that are used frequently

Tags: vue.js

I've come to realize that with my Vue components I frequently need to work with several elements from the template and I don't want to keep querying for them so what I've come to do is save them in the data like so:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="header">Hello World!</h1>
        <span class="subheader">I love Vue</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "MyComponent",

    data() {
        return {
            elements: {},
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.elements.header = document.querySelector('.header');
        this.elements.subheader = document.querySelector('.subheader');
    }
}
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine of course but it doesn't feel very Vue to me. Is there a recommended way of doing this with Vue or is it recommended to just query elements as they're needed?

Comment: You are trying to repeat the traditional targeting mode as vanilla or jquery but [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) works with his self ecosystem to use the DOM and it is not necessarily as we did time ago.

Comment: You are not storing the DOM element in your `data`, but a reference to it. You shouldn't assume that's necessarily faster before actually testing it. Besides, considering how fast `querySelector` is, chances are the difference is insignificant. The more important question here is: what are you doing with those elements? And why aren't you using the provided `$refs`, which was designed specifically for this purpose?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You are completely right about the `$refs`, I'm using them elsewhere in my application but I didn't think to use them in this scenario. I also have been using them sparingly but I thought I remembered reading some documentation where it said `$refs` should be used sparingly but I can't seem to find it now so maybe its outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defenitely should use `refs` to access DOM elements everywhere. [Referecne](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="header" ref="header">Hello World!</h1>
        <span class="subheader" ref="subheader">I love Vue</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "MyComponent",

    data() {
        return {
            elements: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        someMethod() {
           console.log(this.$refs.header);
           console.log(this.$refs.subheader);
         }
    }
}
</script>
```